# Pandas Sum Values Based on Unique Values

Tags: pandas

I am trying to sum the total of unique values in a pandas data frame but for some reason I am having difficulty getting just one number for each unique values.

```
   A          B          C        D
  calmuni   30,000.00   CA  1-3 year paper  
  calmuni   95,000.00   CA  1-3 year paper  
  massmuni  25,000.00   MA  1-3 year paper  
  massmuni  30,000.00   RI  1-3 year paper  
  massmuni  175,000.00  MA  1-3 year paper
```

I am trying to sum column B based off the unique values in column A but my groupby function isn't working. I would like to one line item sum value for each unique value:

```
orders.groupby('A')['B'].sum()
A
calmuni       30,000.0095,000.00125,000.0020,000.0020,000.00...
massmuni      25,000.0030,000.00175,000.0025,000.0050,000.00..
```

Comment: df.B=pd.to_numeric(df.B.replace({',':''}))

Comment: thanks Wen! Didn't realize the comma